# C# new Dictionary<string, object>() is IDictionary<object, object> return false

Tags: c#

Example:

```
void Main()
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    Console.WriteLine(dic is IDictionary<object, object>); //False
    Console.WriteLine(dic is IDictionary<dynamic, dynamic>); //False
    Console.WriteLine(dic is IDictionary<string, object>); //True
}
```

Isn't string an object, too ? why `dic is IDictionary<object, object>` get false.

Comment: A `IDictionary<object, object>` means **any object** can be a key. That doesn't make sense for your `dic`. It won't take any object as a key. It will take **only strings**.

Comment: See Covariance and Contravariance:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Summary**

Beside understanding `Covariance-Contravariance` from the links posted, which are applicable to interfaces and delegates, let's understand the issue in little more detail, following is the implementation of the [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0), it implements `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, where both types `Tkey` and `TValue` are invariant, neither only Covariant, nor only Contravariant, which simply means that both of them can be in the input and output positions depending upon the method or property, certainly the type compatibility is important, while implementing those methods / properties.

> **Let's assume following is a valid code:**

`Dictionary<string,object> : IDictionary<object,object>`, then what it means is:

Considering only `TKey`, as that is only different, in the Contravariant positions `in`, like `bool ContainsKey(TKey key);`, you are supplying `string` but it is accepting `object`, which is fine, since `object` is the base class, but Covariant positions `out` will be a trouble, in something like `ICollection<TKey> Keys {get;}`, since you are willing to return any `object` everything in .Net C# can be typecasted to the `object` type, but caller is expecting only `string`.

> **Code Above will not even compile**

`Dictionary` code above will not even compile, your confusion is from the viewpoint is if I can assign a `string` type to an `object` type, then why not `Dictionary<string,object>` to `IDictionary<object,object>`, simply because `Dictionary` in itself an open generic type implementation, which is closed when types are assigned before being used, here the mapping is for the `Dictionary` type, which can itself be assigned to `object` base class not for the individual types used to create a closed data structure, therefore its important to match them to ensure that all methods with types at any position can work seamlessly.

> **Interesting case of `IEnumerable<out T>`**

In fact, [`IEnumerable<out T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs,3acf01620172c7f0) is an interesting example, it has covariant `type T`, this is base interface for all collections in .Net, here we can have a `List<ChildClass>` supplied to the `IEnumerable<Baseclass>`, since `Baseclass` is only in the output position, so can accept any child class object, in fact this incompatibility was one of the reason to introduce Covariance and Contravariance, otherwise it was not possible to do the assignment with an invariant type, which is was not in line with the developer expectation

> **Check out the code snippet to understand the difference:**

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    var isTrue = list is IEnumerable<object>;

    isTrue.Print(); // Prints True

    isTrue = dictionary is IDictionary<object,object>;

    isTrue.Print(); // Prints False

    isTrue = dictionary is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object,object>>;

    isTrue.Print(); // Prints False, KeyValuePair<string,object> is not same 
  //as KeyValuePair<object,object>, there's no default compatibility

    isTrue = dictionary is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;

    isTrue.Print(); // Prints True
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`String` derives from an `Object`. But `IDictionary<string, object>` does not derive from `IDictionary<object, object>`. That is why it returns false. You may want to read about Covariance and Contravariance concept in .NET
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance